# How to remove read more on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web

How can I remove that readmore button on my site (wordpress)?

`the_content( __( 'Read more &rarr;', 'ward' ) );`

Answer (score 3):

Better to do with a filter - that way you do not need to change all the theme´s files and search for the specific code ..

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'my_more_link', 10, 2 );

function my_more_link( $more_link, $more_link_text ) {
$my_custom_more = "Continue reading this post"; // leave NULL to diable
    return str_replace( $more_link_text, $my_custom_more, $more_link );
}
```

and use `add_filter('excerpt_more', 'my_more_link');` for excerpts in much the same way

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

`the_content( __( 'Read more &rarr;', 'ward' ) );`

With:

`the_excerpt();`

Or you can use CSS `display:none;` on the element to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

better filter.

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'disable_more_link', 10, 2 );

function disable_more_link( $more_link, $more_link_text ) {
    return;
}
```

This will probably disable all.. not tested yet ..

Answer (score 0):

From the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More):

`<?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>`

The $more_link_text sets the link text like "Read More". The second one, $strip_teaser, sets whether or not the "more" link should be hidden (TRUE) or displayed (FALSE). The default is FALSE, which shows the link text.

To remove the teaser:

Change the_content(); in your index.php to (i.e., the second parameter controls this):

`the_content('',FALSE,'');`